# React Native return function doesn't properly add numbers

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using React Native and Firebase firestore for a project.

In firestore, the doc has a field called teammates. In that field, there is an array, with maps inside ( nested objects ) that have the following fields: key(int, starting from 0), name, field.

Problem is, I want to return in the View key+1 so that the ID stars from 1 not 0. This works for the first map inside array, for key 0, but starting with key = 1 in firebase, it returns ID 11 instead of ID 1+1(2)

```
<FlatList
                
       
       data={post}
       
       renderItem={({ item }) => (
          
          <View>
                   {item.teammates.map((item) => (
                       <View>
                       <Text>ID: {item.key + 1}</Text>
                       <Text>Name: {item.name}</Text>
                       </View>
                       
                   ))}


           </View>
           

       )}

   />
```

Comment: sounds like item.key is a string not a number, try wrapping it in [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: Thanks a lot man! That saved me! But item.key is a number, according to firestore database. Weird

Comment: Consider Posting Answer too, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `item.key` is a string, you will need to parse it first into a `number`, then you can add `+1`. Something like

```js
<Text>ID: {parseInt(item.key, 10) + 1}</Text>
```